# Sort All innerHTML Based on First innerHTML Order and Extract To Other innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have two `div`(s) where contains of data with the same class `judul_post` and `list_hrg`:

```
<div class="judul_post">Celana Dalam XXXL dari Australia</div>
<div class="judul_post">Celana Dalam Jadul Tapi Sakti</div>
<div class="judul_post">Celana Dalam Borobudur Mahal</div>
<div class="judul_post">Celana Superman Asli dari Hongkong</div>
<div class="judul_post">Celana Baja Anti Api Air Asli</div>
```

---

```
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam XXXL dari Australia</span>
    <span class="cHarga">100</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam Jadul Tapi Sakti</span>
    <span class="cHarga">200</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam Borobudur Mahal</span>
    <span class="cHarga">300</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Superman Asli dari Hongkong</span>
    <span class="cHarga">400</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Baja Anti Api Air Asli</span>
    <span class="cHarga">500</span>
</div>
```

---

**What I want to achieve are:**

**FIRST:** All `innerHTML` in `prod_name` must be the same (sorted) as in `judul_post`. **Result should be like:**

```
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam XXXL dari Australia</span>
    <span class="cHarga">100</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam Jadul Tapi Sakti</span>
    <span class="cHarga">200</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam Borobudur Mahal</span>
    <span class="cHarga">300</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Superman Asli dari Hongkong</span>
    <span class="cHarga">400</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
    <span class="prod_name">Celana Baja Anti Api Air Asli</span>
    <span class="cHarga">500</span>
</div>
```

**SECOND:** All `innerHTML` in class `cHarga` are moved to this following `showHargaProd` and sorted based on FIRST above.

```
<div class="showHargaProd">100</div>
<div class="showHargaProd">200</div>
<div class="showHargaProd">300</div>
<div class="showHargaProd">400</div>
<div class="showHargaProd">500</div>
```

**I GET STUCK:**
I try with this follows, but it doesn't achieve both targets above:

```
<script>
// identify
var judul_post = document.querySelectorAll('.judul_post');
var cHarga = document.querySelectorAll('.cHarga');
var prod_name = document.querySelectorAll('.prod_name');
var showHargaProd = document.querySelectorAll('.showHargaProd');

    <script>
    function showDivValues(){
        for(var i = 0; i < judul_post.length; i++){
    
            var btnsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(lst_hrg[i].innerHTML);
            if (btnsArr = judul_post[i].innerHTML){
                lst_hrg[i].innerHTML = judul_post[i].innerHTML;
                console.log('YES ' + cHarga[i].innerHTML);
                }
            else{
                console.log('NO ' + cHarga[i].innerHTML);
                }
    
    
    
            //console.log(cHarga[i].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    showDivValues();
```

From the efforts above `cHarga[i]innerHTML` in `showHargaProd` doesn't sort based on on `judul_post[i].innerHTML`.

I think I need something to **match** each `innerHTML` of `judul_post` with `innerHTML` of `prod_name`. When each of the two match, sort them.

Any help would be appreciated! (pls do not use jquery since my web is in AMP-HTML).

Comment: You have enough rep to know that you should provide the code you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: @disinfor, I updated my question with necessary things to achieve the point of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you would want to order the `.list_hrg` items based on their order in `.judul_post`. If so, then you can try something like below:

```js
var data = document.querySelectorAll('.judul_post');
var objData = {};

//store index of data in their correct order into an object
//with the text as their key
data.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  var txt = val.innerText;
  objData[txt] = idx;
});

var orig = document.querySelectorAll('.list_hrg');
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(orig); //convert to array

//sort array using the index in our `objData`
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aName = a.querySelector('.prod_name').innerText;
  var bName = b.querySelector('.prod_name').innerText;
  return objData[aName] - objData[bName];
});

console.log('sorted', arr.map(i => i.innerText));

//do whatever you like with the sorted `arr`
```

```html
<b>DATA</b>:
<div class="judul_post">Celana Dalam XXXL dari Australia</div>
<div class="judul_post">Celana Dalam Jadul Tapi Sakti</div>
<div class="judul_post">Celana Dalam Borobudur Mahal</div>
<div class="judul_post">Celana Superman Asli dari Hongkong</div>
<div class="judul_post">Celana Baja Anti Api Air Asli</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<b>ORIGINAL</b>:
<div class="list_hrg">
  <span class="prod_name">Celana Superman Asli dari Hongkong</span>
  <span class="cHarga">400</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
  <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam Jadul Tapi Sakti</span>
  <span class="cHarga">200</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
  <span class="prod_name">Celana Baja Anti Api Air Asli</span>
  <span class="cHarga">500</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
  <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam XXXL dari Australia</span>
  <span class="cHarga">100</span>
</div>
<div class="list_hrg">
  <span class="prod_name">Celana Dalam Borobudur Mahal</span>
  <span class="cHarga">300</span>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
```

**NOTE:**

I shuffled the `.list_hrg` items just to show that the sorting works. That was a problem in your question as you were talking about sorting but your initial and expected outputs show no change.

Comment: yes, I use the word `sort` to emphasize that the `.list_hrg` which contains `prod_name` must be the *same order* as in `judul_post` and you did it. - then, I will try other different experiments again in the future question :)